# Path planning to follow another car parallely

Tags: ros, motion-planning, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hej guys,

I am currently working on a project where i have to create trajectories(set of waypoints) for a rc car in such a way it follows another car parallely. I have the GPS signals for both cars. The trajectory generated should have a structure(x,y,v). The rc car is in a good state to follow the (x,y,v). The controllers to follow the waypoints is working good. Now i have to have a mathematical idea to relate the (x,y,v) of the rc car and another car(x,y,v) in such a way it runs in parallel .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237197/path-planning-to-follow-another-car-parallely/) by [surizer](https://answers.ros.org/users/27192/surizer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my opinion, A is head, B is afterward, set B to follow A's trajectory but with a safety offset from A. is it OK?
or you can refer to turtlebot's (two) follower case.

---

Originally posted by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) with karma: 255 on 2016-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [surizer](https://answers.ros.org/users/27192/surizer/) on 2016-06-20**:
Hey the problem is offset , A constant offset wont make it run parallel. i would like to know a mathematical formula with heading that can probably change the offset.